# Where are located heroku files created by code?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm currently coding a chatbot on nodeJS. I create a file for each of the clients who are talking to my bot. To do so I create a folder /tmp/user_data/... 
But I cannot figure out where is he located on heroku. I tried to go on the bash and do some grep/ls commands but nothing.

Moreover I don't understand why when I create my folder at ./... (the root of the code folder) it works on local but not on heroku? Do process runs the code on a temp folder or somewhat?

Thanks !

Comment: they are in /tmp  . see 'ephemeral filesystem' in link : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

Comment: Yeah but I can't see them in tmp. I only see a folder /mask which doesnt allow me to explore it